# Is there a way to make admin changes to Firestore without triggering onUpdate Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Simple question.

I'm using Firebase Cloud Functions. Is there a way to change user data without trigger onUpdate? So i have an onUpdate that sends me an email whenever a user changes data, so that i know what's going on. But there are times when i have to publish, unpublish etc user data and this triggers cloud functions email. Is there a way to not trigger the email, like say "if this is an admin change, then don't send the email".

Or, is there a better way to track user changes to Firestore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to not trigger the email, like say "if this is an admin change, then don't send the email".

There is no such thing as "admin" access in this respect, and there is no other built-in way to avoid running an update trigger when a matching document is updated.  The only information you have available when the trigger runs is the contents of the document itself, so your only option is to check the contents and decide from there if the trigger should do nothing.  This means you could possibly write some field in the document during the same update to signal that no action should be taken.

See also:

- [update document attribute without triggering onUpdate() with cloud functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58559367/update-document-attribute-without-triggering-onupdate-with-cloud-functions)
- [Is there a way to suppress Firebase Functions Firestore triggers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59314716/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-firebase-functions-firestore-triggers)
- [Can I avoid triggering a Google Cloud Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69258690/can-i-avoid-triggering-a-google-cloud-function)